# Find the range of the piecewise function

Tags: functions

Find the range of the function defined by f(x)= {2x+ 1 , x≤2 ;  8-x, x>2}

I thought the range of the function should be y<6.
However, the solution says that there are no y values between 5 and 6, therefore the range is ]-∞,5] ∪ ]6,∞[

Through the graph, it can clearly be seen that y values do exist between 5 and 6, so what is the answer?

[image]

Comment: $y<6$ is correct.

Comment: Check that you didn't misread /miscopy the problem from its source. While errors in textbooks do happen, the fact that it's not just the difference between $y<6$ and $y<5$ but actually all numbers above 6 are also given as a solution suggests that you may not have copied the function definition above 2 correctly.